# Whats the solution here? want to re-use the same controller with different data

Tags: angularjs

I have a grid like this

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    ...
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-header">
            <h3>Showing {{users.records}} Users</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-con">
            <div class="grid-con-header row">
                <div ng-click="sortOrder($event, 'fullName')" class="col-xs-4 sortable"><span>Name</span></div>
                <div ng-click="sortOrder($event, 'emailAddress')" class="col-xs-4 sortable"><span>Email</span></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-con-body">
                <div ng-hide="isGridLoading" class="row" ng-repeat="row in users.rows">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">                            
                        <a href="users/modify/1">{{row.fullName}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">{{row.emailAddress}}</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <a ng-href="#/users/modify/{{row.loginId}}" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Modify</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="row ajax-ngview" ng-show="isGridLoading"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my UserCtrl

```
function UsersCtrl($scope, Users) {
    $scope.grid = {
        "_search": '',
        "page": 1,
        "rows": 10,
        "sidx": "loginId",
        "sord": "asc"
    };
    $scope.users = {};    
    updateGrid();

    function updateGrid() {
        $scope.isGridLoading = true;
        Users.get($scope.grid).$promise.then(function(result) {
            $scope.users = result;
            $scope.isGridLoading = false;            

        }, function(reason) {

        });
    }

    $scope.sortOrder = function(event, name) {
        ...
    }

}
```

I want to show this type of grid on multiple pages, I am not sure what best solution is here. Do I need to copy the UserCtrl and paste it as some like GroupCtrol and modify it as required or is there some better solution?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a generic grid that works with various models? To me that sounds like something you could solve with a custom directive, perhaps where you specify the model for the grid with ng-model.

Comment: Yes... a generic grid with various models. I dont want to re-write the function UserCtrl to something else like GroupCtrl other pages.

Comment: I think a custom directive is what you'd want to do...but I'm not 100% on that. You can read up on that and I may work on a JSfiddle later that may or may not be relevant if someone comes in with an answer soon (or you figure it out) :)

Comment: No, actually I dont need directive. I can create GridCtrl method the same as UserCtrl, but dont know how to pass factory object to that GridCtrol. Something like on User page want to pass factory object 'User' to ng-controller="GridCtrl", on group page want to pass factory object 'Group' to ng-controller="GridCtrl"... possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)**'s `resolve` property, to pass the appropriate model as a dependency:

```
/* First "generify" the controller */
angular.module('myApp').controller('gridCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
    $scope.grid = {
        "_search": '',
        "page": 1,
        "rows": 10,
        "sidx": "loginId",
        "sord": "asc"
    };
    $scope.data = {};
    updateGrid();

    function updateGrid() {
        $scope.isGridLoading = true;
        Data.get($scope.grid).$promise.then(function (result) {
            $scope.data = result;
            $scope.isGridLoading = false;
        }, function (reason) {...});
    }
    ...

/* Second, configure $routeProvider to pass 
 * the appropriate model to each view */
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/users', {
        templateUrl: 'grid.html',
        controller:  'gridCtrl',
        resolve: {
            Data: 'Users'
        }
    })
    .when('/groups', {
        templateUrl: 'grid.html',
        controller:  'gridCtrl',
        resolve: {
            Data: 'Groups'
        }
    });
```

So, in the 1st case the `Users` service will be passed as a dependency to the `gridCtrl` controller (under the name of `Data`), whereas in the 2nd case the `Groups` service will be passed (again under the name of `Data`).

---

<sub>For what it's worth, I too do believe a directive would be more appropriate here...</sub>

Comment: I think this helps to demonstrate that a directive is the way to go. While this will get the appropriate model associated with the grid, I would think a lot of the DOM would also have to change to accommodate the different data (e.g., link destinations, descriptive text like "Showing # of Users/Groups", etc.). I could also be totally misunderstanding the need here.

Comment: @ExpertSystem thnx a lot, thats exactly what I was looking for